# c++ winapi - subclassing an edit control - annoying sound when clicking "Enter"

Tags: c++, winapi, subclassing

I made an edit control able to accept data when somebody would click "Enter". I used subclassing to do that. It worked almost perfectly. However after clicking "Enter" the system plays "Error" sound every time. I tried to use ES_MULTILINE and ES_AUTOVSCROLL to bypass it but it helped partially. Now after clicking "Enter" there's no sound, but in the textbox appears useless "Enter" character, that is impossible to delete.
How to bypass the system sound? Or delete "Enter" character from that textbox (SetWindowText(handle, "") doesn't help).

Comment: Did you try `ES_WANTRETURN`?

Comment: It beeps because it doesn't make sense to press Enter in an edit control that's not multi-line.  Enter is reserved to operate the default control of a window, like the OK button.  Why are you pressing useless keys?  What is supposed to happen instead?

Comment: @nwp - ES_WANTREURN didn't change anything.

Comment: @Hans Passant - What do you mean by pressing useless keys? I want to make convenient way to confirm data instead of clicking a button using mouse.

Comment: No real idea what "confirm data" might mean.  Sounds to me you are trying to write a console mode program.  That's not how a GUI program is supposed to be designed.  The Enter key operates the default control, the user presses the Tab key or the cursor keys to change the focus.

Comment: @HansPassant: I've had the request very often from customers that pressing Enter should focus the next edit field. Especially if the program was to replace an old text mode data entry application. The users don't care about Windows UI guidelines, they want the key sequences to stay the same, muscle memory and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need the `ES_MULTILINE`, `ES_AUTOVSCROLL` or `ES_WANTRETURN` style flags.

To stop a single-line edit control from beeping on `VK_RETURN` you need to handle the `WM_CHAR` message for that control and return 0 for `VK_RETURN` without calling the default window procedure, which has to be called for all other keys.

Comment: You do not need to handle the `WM_KEYDOWN` message. If you're not handling `WM_KEYDOWN` default processing (through a call to `TranslateMessage`) will produce one or more `WM_CHAR` messages. Handling `WM_CHAR` is sufficient to prevent the beep.

Comment: See [How to turn off beeping when pressing ENTER on a single-line EDIT control under Windows CE?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3590126/1377770) for a code example.

Answer (score 3):

I learned from WinAPI Reference that default processing of `WM_CHAR` for an edit calls `MessageBeep` function for an illegal character, such as enter and tab.  I had subclassed the edit control to tab between controls by intercepting `WM_KEYDOWN` (as shown by Petzold for scroll bars), but it was beeping when I pressed tab.  So I intercept `WM_CHAR` to avoid default processing when I press tab, and so stop the beep.