# Ding sound on pressing Enter

Tags: c++, builder

i used to write this code

```
if(Edit1->Text != "" && Key == VK_RETURN){
 Edit1->Text = Edit1->Text.Trim();
 Edit2->SetFocus();
}
```

and it works just fine, till I used C++ builder Xe6. the ding sound come up each time I press Enter button.
any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beep sound is the default behavior on your IDE. Try:

```
if(Edit1->Text != "" && Key == VK_RETURN){
    Key=0;
    Edit1->Text = Edit1->Text.Trim();
    Edit2->SetFocus();
}
```

Alternate solution:
[How to turn off beeping when pressing ENTER on a single-line EDIT control under Windows CE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588526/how-to-turn-off-beeping-when-pressing-enter-on-a-single-line-edit-control-under)

Comment: You may wanna checK http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?433911-TextBox-Enter-click-DING